# How to detect if iPhone/iPod camera supports video?

Tags: iphone

Is there a better way than using sysctlbyname to find the device model and filtering by supported models? I'm hoping for something clean like:
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])

ANSWER: In the process of writing this, I found the answer. To keep anyone else from searching like I did, here you go:

```
NSArray *media = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

if ([media containsObject:@"public.movie"] == YES)
  NSLog(@"Video Supported");
else 
  NSLog(@"Video Not Supported");
```

Comment: You should delete the question then.

Comment: I disagree. He should answer his own question and accept it so that others searching for something similar will be able to find it.

Comment: You should beater use kUTTypeMovie instead of @"public.movie" because it's value can change in future.